# adjusting height & width of div - Html layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have changed my layout from table to div. I have created a layout but still something is missing from my side. My gui is not occupying the full browser.

Still two problem :---
1> I want to keep the width of second div (main menu) constant & allow third div (table center) to extend to extreme right.
2> Also by default height of GUI occupy the full webpage browser (at present bottom of the page is in white colour).

Also how can i get the default height & with of my browser ?

code :---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>

div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

</style>

<body>


<div id= "images"; class=scrollable colspan="2" style="background-color:#CC99FF; white-space:nowrap; float:left;">

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

</div>


<div id= "Menu" style="background-color:#FFCCFF; height:400px;width:200px;float:left;">

      <b>Main Menu</b><br />
      BUTTON-1<br />
      BUTTON-2<br />
      BUTTON-3

</div>


<div id= "center" style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:200px;width:400px; float:left;">
        Table center

</div>

<div id= "fotter" style="background-color:#CC99FF; clear:both;text-align:center;">
      Copyright © 2014 My First Layout
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Your basic html needs some work in the above code. You have no HEAD tag. This should be placed before the body tag and should contain your style tag. You also seem to have two body tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you on the right path :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/3uj9P/15/)**

I mande many changes to your code and I won't list them all. The main changes :

**HTML**

- errors in HTML
- Put the styles in a proper CSS stylesheet (you should do the same and not use inline styles in HTML markup).

**CSS**

- Used `position:absolute;` on all elements exept the scrollable image div so that your layout uses the whole window, more info [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

CSS :

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
#images {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#Menu {
    background-color:#FFCCFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    bottom:20px;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
}
#center {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    left:200px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#fotter {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="images" class="scrollable">
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
    <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
</div>
<div id="Menu"> <b>Main Menu</b>

    <br />BUTTON-1
    <br />BUTTON-2
    <br />BUTTON-3</div>
<div id="center">Table center</div>
<div id="fotter">Copyright © 2014 My First Layout</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need to use float:left on that center one, just simply use `width:100%;`
2. There is whitespace because the height of the page is not equal to the screen's height.
   If you wish to put the footer to the very bottom use:

   .fotter
   {
    position:absolute;bottom:0;
   }

(I had to change it to class from ID,because my comment did not showed the "#")

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
html,body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>


<body>


<div id= "images"; class=scrollable colspan="2" style="background-color:#CC99FF; white-space:nowrap; float:left;">

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

</div>


<div id= "Menu" style="background-color:#FFCCFF; height:400px;width:200px;float:left;">

      <b>Main Menu</b><br />
      BUTTON-1<br />
      BUTTON-2<br />
      BUTTON-3

</div>


<div id= "center" style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:200px;width:100%;">
        Table center

</div>

<div class="fotter" style="background-color:#CC99FF; clear:both;text-align:center;">
      Copyright © 2014 My First Layout
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<style>

div.scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}


</style>

<body style="height: 100%;">


<div id= "images"; class=scrollable colspan="2" style="background-color:#CC99FF; white-space:nowrap; float:left;">

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

<input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS6QBsJ91Xp2YoqjiDe4qbYAGSf8deoyI0c1TutLDPrxwuQb34-" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />

</div>


<div id= "Menu" style="background-color:#FFCCFF;width:200px; height:100%; float:left;">

      <b>Main Menu</b><br />
      BUTTON-1<br />
      BUTTON-2<br />
      BUTTON-3

</div>


<div id= "center" style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:100% ">
<p>
        Table center
      </p>


</div>
<div id= "fotter" style="background-color:#CC99FF; clear:both;text-align:center;">
      Copyright © 2014 My First Layout
</div>

</body>
</html>
```